# Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt3 + \sqrt5$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> Find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt3 + \sqrt5$ over $\Bbb Q$.

I got that if $\alpha = \sqrt3 + \sqrt5$, then $\alpha^2 = 8+2\sqrt{15}$ and from there $\alpha^2 - 8 = 2\sqrt{15}$. Squaring again to get rid of the radical I get that $$(\alpha^2-8)^2 = 60 \iff \alpha^4 - 16\alpha^2 + 4 = 0$$

but looking at the solution the minimal polynoimal should be $x^4 -10x^3 +1$. How did they come to that conclusion?

Comment: No idea, but what you did looks fine.  See [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=minimal+polynomial+sqrt%283%29%2Bsqrt%285%29) for confirmation.

Comment: Minimal polynomial is unique up to a nonzero constant factor. Thus, at most one of $x^4-16x^2+4$ and $x^4-10x^3+1$ can be right. Because yours is right, theirs must be wrong.

Comment: The minimal polynomial is not $x^4-10x^3+1$. That would make $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ an algebraic integer unit, but it is not.

Comment: $(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^4 -10(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})^3 + 1 = 124+32\sqrt{15} - 10(18\sqrt{3}+14\sqrt{5}) + 1 = 125 - 180\sqrt{3}-140\sqrt{5}+32\sqrt{15}\neq 0$.

Comment: "The solution" really can't be right because you can see that the roots of the minimal polynomial will be $\pm \sqrt 3\pm \sqrt 5$, and in particular the negative of any root will be a root. The minimal polynomial must therefore be even (contain only even powers of $x$).

Comment: This was example $8$ in "Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications". Looking at the newest version it seems to be corrected to be the same as what I got.